# How to check specific value in a specific document field and operate it in mongodb syntax

Tags: node.js, mongodb

These are my documents as below:

```
{
    "user" : "test",
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "song" : [
            {
                    "song" : "Torn Between Two Lovers",
                    "artist" : "Mary MacGregor",
                    "insertDate" : ISODate("2021-07-16T02:42:30.191Z")
            },
            {
                            "song" : "Theme from A Summer Place",
                            "artist" : "Percy Faith",
                            "insertDate" : ISODate("2021-07-16T02:43:08.052Z")
                    }
            ],
    "user" : "test2",
    "email" : "test2@test.com",
    "song" : [
            {
                    "song" : "Rock with you",
                    "artist" : "Michael Jackson",
                    "insertDate" : ISODate("2021-07-16T02:42:30.191Z")
            }  
            ]
}
```

When I got a email with a song , How to check if the song exists in the song array.
If exists delete it.
If not exists insert it.

I use code as below,Find all songs of the user-test and check in node.js syntax.

How can I do with mongodb syntax directly? Thank you!!

```
let query = {{"user": "test"},{song:1}};
db.collection("user").findOne(query, (err, result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use two queries in such case.

```
   let result = await db1.find({ email: "test@test.com" }).toArray();
var song = result[0].song ? result[0].song : [];
let index = song.findIndex(x => x.song === data.song)
if (index >= 0)
    song = song.filter(x => x.song !== data.song);
else
    song.push(data)
let result1 = await db1.findOneAndUpdate({ email: "test@test.com" }, { $set: { song: song } });
```